# Ftp'd files have secure deletion attribute set

Tags: centos, vsftpd, xattr

I have recently upgraded to a LAMP server running on Centos 7, with vsftpd for uploading files.

As a hack, I use the secure deletion attribute to tag certain files to keep track of which ones clients have downloaded via our webpage. This relied on that fact that files uploaded via ftp did not have the 's' attribute set, and when clients downloaded the file, I set the 's' attribute, thus marking it as 'downloaded'.

Now, on this new server, files uploaded via vsftpd have the 's' attribute set automagically. As soon as I upload a file, if I lsattr, I can see it set.

Anyone have any idea why/how this is happening? I thought it might be an SELinux thing, but I don't believe that is the case.

Is this something vsftpd is doing? Or is it indeed an SELinux thing? Something else? Any help is appreciated.

edit: I can confirm that this is not SELinux related, as I have disabled and the issue persists.

Comment: Remember directory permissions propogate downward to files/directories (including some extended attributes if I recall).

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That was the issue...I didn't know that the parent directory had the flag set, nor did I realize it would be inherited. Must have been done by accident. The simplest things...

Comment: Also note the `BUGS AND LIMITATIONS` section of `chattr(1)`: _»The 'c', 's', and 'u' attributes are not honored by the ext2, ext3, and ext4 filesystems as implemented in the current mainline Linux kernels.«_